# Meaning of the sentence without "for"

Tags: meaning, prepositions

*If it weren't for Jim, this company would be in a mess.*

*If it weren't Jim, this company would be in a mess.*

What is the function of "for" in the first sentence? And if we remove it from the sentence ,as in the second sentence, is the meaning distorted? Why?

Comment: _For_ means _because of_ in that sentence. If you remove it, the sentence makes no sense because you say the company _is_ Jim. Unless you explain why you think you can remove a (random?) word form a sentence, I don't think this question is very valuable.

Comment: [If it were not for](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/if-it-were-not-for-if-it-had-not-been-for) is a standard phrase in English.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> If it weren't Jim, this company would be in a mess.

Is nonsensical, since it means "If the company was not Jim..."  But this doesn't make sense, since "Jim" is person, not a company.

On the other hand

> If it were not for Jim, This company would be in a mess

Is an idiom, meaning that the reason that the company is not in a mess is because Jim has done something to prevent it.